# Limit number of images user can upload

Tags: django

I have a blog feature on my site, users can upload a single main image and multiple supporting images. The issue I am facing is I want to be able to limit the number of images a user can upload. I understand that I could use a for loop on it but if the user goes back later and adds more it would make the for loop useless. So I figured the best way to do this would be to add a field to the model that would count the number of images uploaded and then I can use an if statement to check if more than a said number of images have been uploaded. How would i go about getting the number of images and adding them to the post while it is being created. Or should I go about this a different way

view

```
    @login_required
def createPostView(request):

    currentUser = request.user
    postForm = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if postForm.is_valid():
            PostFormID = postForm.save(commit=False)
            PostFormID.author = request.user
            PostFormID.save()                   
            
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):          
                test = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if test.is_valid():
                    instance = test.save(commit=False)
                    instance.post_id = PostFormID.id
                    instance.images = f
                    instance.save()   
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
               
    return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'postForm': postForm, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the total items in a list before looping by using len.

```
len(request.FILES.getlist('images'))
>>> 10
```

So something like:

```
if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) > 3:
    raise Exception("Only three images allowed")
else:
   // process the images in the for loop
```